# Swift-Sodium: Scalar Multiplication

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, libsodium, sodium

I am using **SwiftSodium**(https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium) for encryption process in my project.

I need to perform **scalar multiplication** of public and private key.

ScarMultiplication wrapper class was available in **libsodium .net** version **but not in Swift**(SwiftSodium).

Any help on how to achieve the scalar multiplication is highly appreciable.

Thanks.